# How to display complete image in card div with same aspect ratio and letterboxing using Material-UI?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

All I want to do is show a product image exactly how ebay does:
[image]

Their product image aspect ratio remains the same with white space to fill in the remaining space in the container div. From what I understand, the purpose of `objectFit: 'contain'` is meant exactly to do this but I can't seem to figure it out. Below are my Material-UI components and CSS stylings. I believe the `container` class is correct, but how what should height and width of CardMedia be? I've tried max-width and max-height and some other attempts, but can't for the life of me figure this out.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  imageContainer: {
    height: '400px',
    width: '400px',
    margin: 'auto'
  },
  media: {
    height: '400px',
    objectFit: 'contain',
  },
})

function ProductDetails() {
  return (
      <Grid container spacing={2}  >
        <Grid item  xs={12} md={6}>
          <Card className={classes.imageContainer}>
            <CardMedia
                className={classes.media}
                image={'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/23AAAOSwZrJgJHIg/s-l1600.jpg'}
             />
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
  )
}
```

Comment: I understand the current height of `media` is not right at the 400px, but left it there so the image would display

Comment: Can you give us a codesandbox with your example ?